What is the norm of an ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?
Question: What is the norm of an ideal $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?
Basically, I use the usual norm. $N(a)=a.\overline a=a^2+5db^2$
I know that if ideal is generated by one element then its norm is exactly the same as norm of a generator. For example, if $I_1=(2)$ then Norm$(I_1)=4$ and Norm$(I_2)=6$ where $I_2=(1+\sqrt{-5})$.
What is the norm of non-principle ideal? How can I calculate norm of $I$?

Are you asking for the general definition or rather for how to compute an ideal norm in this specific ring?  Where did you encounter it without definition?

I want to learn that how can I compute norm of non-principle ideal like $I$.

Generally we can write the ideal as a module  in Hermite normal form - which makes the norm obvious, e.g. see this answer and the posts Linked there, and also here (yours follows the same way).

For Galois extensions, the norm to $\mathbb{Z}$ of $I$ is $\mathbb{Z}\cap\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(I)$, where $G$ is the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This is not hard to do here.

You can use Hermite normal form, like Bill Dubuque suggests.
However, you have two alternative ways to proceed.
(1) You can show that $(2)=I\bar{I}$, then use multiplicativity of the norm and the fact that $\bar{I}$ and $I$ have same norm to get $N(I)=2$.
(2) You can simply use the definition, but you have to identify the quotient ring. This is easy here: if $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, the ring morphism $m\in\mathbb{Z}\mapsto m+I\in R/I$ is surjective (because $a+b\sqrt{-5}\equiv a-b \mod I$), with kernel $2\mathbb{Z}$ (exercise).
Hence $R/I\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $N(I)=2$ again.
